# How to Access rest api (deployed in k8 cluster) via service name

Tags: rest, go, kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

Deployed a rest API(go lang) in kubernetes cluster and also created a service for the pod.

i need to access the rest API via service name or service URL?

Answer (score 1):

It depends from where are you accessing the service.

If you are accessing from the kubernetes cluster nodes, you can access through service IP;  `curl <service-ip>` should provide access to your rest API.

If you are accessing the service from another pod, then you can use internal kubernetes DNS resolution. Something like `curl <service-name>.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local` should access your rest API.

If you want to access rest API outside of the cluster, you need a load balancer with the IP of the cluster external network (the network where cluster resides). If you have deployed cluster on-premise, you may consider using metallb for managing external IPs. If the cluster is deployed in the cloud, then you can use cloud provided IPs.

Comment: It worked  when i used curl service IP.  But curl returns error on '<service-name>.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local'.   Error as follows:     curl: (6) Could not resolve host: app2-service.default.svc.cluster.local; Unknown error.

Comment: is there any way to access service with service  name?